# Jquery conditional selector for TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I want to be able to add a class to a TR element, dependent on the value of the first TD element.

For example:

If I have the following array of data:

[1,2,3,4]
[5,6,7,8]

Where each array represents a tr, with each element being a td, I would like to highlight the TR where the first TD equals 5 for instance.

How would i go about doing this?

Thanks,

Comment: `$('tr').find('td:nth-child(1)').text() == 5` ?

Comment: How are you creating the table? You could just add the class to the `tr` as you generate it...

Comment: @guradio how would i add a class to that??

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, i am creating it through an ajax call and initialising datatables using the aoColumn attribute

Comment: show the html mark up.. you need to loop each tr then put the condition

Comment: Might want to add the tag for datatables then, so that people who know that can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using the fnRowCallback function

```
'fnRowCallback': function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
  $(nRow).css('cursor', 'pointer');
  $(nRow).prop('title', 'Select Company');
  if (aData.CompId === "COMP01") {
    $(nRow).find('td').addClass('selectedCompany');
  }
  return nRow;
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Below example can help!

```js
$(function() {
  var tr = $('tr').find('td:first-child');
  tr.each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == 5)
      $(this).parent('tr').addClass('highlight');
  });
});
```

```css
tr.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I cant seem to get this to work: `var tr = $('#companyStockTable tr').find('td:first-child');
                tr.each(function () {
                    if ($(this).text() == "Company Name I Want")
                        $(this).parent('tr').addClass('selectedCompany');
                });`

Comment: I have managed to solve this now thanks. See my answer below. Seemed the simplest way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `first-child` and [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) with Jquery

```js
$('td:first-child:contains("5")').parent('tr').addClass('selected')
```

```css
tr.selected {
  background: yellow;
}
tr.selected td:first-child {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

<sub>**Edit Note::** This will select all first td with `5` on the string</sub>

Comment: Quick solution, but due to `contains` td with text  "15" will also be selected

Comment: It is valid. Heres a full example but its not working `$('#companyStockTable > td:first-child:contains("This is the selected company")').parent('tr').addClass('selectedCompany');`

Answer (score 0):

Assume the content of the desired row td is "two", either of these would work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var findMe = "two";

  $('#mytable').find('tr').filter(function(index) {
    var isTwo = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text() === findMe;
    return isTwo;
  }).addClass('highlight');

  $('#mytable').find('tr').find('td:first').filter(':contains("' + findMe + '")').parent('tr').addClass('highlight');

});
```